# Prevent XSS Attack and encode correctly characters

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, xss

i have the function for prevent sql injection
is an excellent function, really function in prevent attacks but
begin showing problems with characters

the word is "**controle de finanças**"
in var_dump i see string(31) "**controle de finan&Atilde&sectas**"

i´m trying some methods and failing 2 days please help me

```
function Anti_Sql_Injection($string){ 
        if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc') == 'off'){ 
           $string = addslashes($string); 
        }  

        $string = htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES);
        $codes = array("script","java","applet","iframe","meta","object","html","CONCAT","CHAR","FLOOR","RAND", "<", ">", ";", "'","%");

        $string = str_replace($codes,"",$string);

        return $string; 
}
```

Comment: Make sure that nothing in the [XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) can get round your filter. The recommended method to defeat XSS is [output encoding](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Experimental_Minimal_Encoding_Rules), not by stripping certain words. Also use the [`X-XSS-Protection` header](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers) in block mode, or even better use a Content Security Policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
function Anti_Sql_Injection($string){
    if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc') == 'off') {
        $string = addslashes($string);
    }

    $string = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
    $codes = array("script","java","applet","iframe","meta","object","html","CONCAT","CHAR","FLOOR","RAND", "<", ">", ";", "'","%");

    $string = str_replace($codes,"",$string);

    return $string;
}
```

I also would like to tell you about [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). It has built-in SQL injection via prepared statements. Check out [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) tutorial to start with PDO. I know it is kinda old but still valid and well explained.

Comment: @BrunoPinna my pleasure, I'm glad I could help. Wish you best of luck with your project.

Comment: Are you sure that adding "UTF-8" made any difference?  If so, can you demonstrate it?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a function named `Anti_Sql_Injection()` to prevent XSS attacks? [You should be using **Prepared Statements**](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide) to stop SQL injection and an appropriate, separate [strategy for stopping XSS attacks](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know).

Don't try to kill two birds with one stone. You end up altering data.

### XSS prevention made easy

- Are you using a framework that offers context-sensitive XSS escaping?

  - Yes: Use that feature then. Prioritize `autoescape` blocks over manual escape filters (e.g. with [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org)).
  - No: Do you need to allow the user to provide some HTML?

    - Yes: [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org)
    - No: `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');`

### SQL Injection prevention made easy

Use prepared statements. A library like [EasyDB](https://github.com/paragonie/easydb) (which wraps PDO) can make it less painful to migrate.